# How to set get_users = multi roles?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm new to WP codex can you help me guys on how can i make this multiple roles instead of subscribers only?

```
$blogusers = get_users( 'blog_id=1&orderby=nicename&role=subscriber');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$roles = array('subscriber', 'custom_role1', 'custom_role2');
$users = array();
foreach($roles as $role){
    $args = array(
                 'blog_id' => 1,
                 'orderby' => 'nicename',
                 'role' => $role
                 );
    $current_role_users = get_users($args);
    $users = array_merge($current_role_users, $users);
}
```

Comment: great thanks but it was showing all users even i removed the subscriber role,`$roles = array('administrator', 'mrg-admin', 'reviewer');
$args = array(
             'blog_id' => 1,
             'orderby' => 'nicename',
             'role' => $roles
             );
$blogusers = get_users($args);` can it be set to show roles name? eg. administrator, reviewer, submitter NOT display name?

Comment: Check updated solution. And do you want to get the user's roles? You can access the `roles` property of a user. See [WP_User](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User) class

Answer (score 2):

you can use `role__in` argument.

Example:

```
$args = array( 
    'role__in' => array('administrator','shop_manager'),
    'fields' => 'all',
);
$users = get_users($args);
```

Comment: Most easiest solution for me, thank you

Answer (score 1):

2021 Update. As per https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/211916/show-all-author-products-from-specific-category

I am putting this here as the question was more relevant on google results for what I was lookin for.

**author__in (array) - use author id (available since Version 3.7).**

eg

```
$roles=array('administrator','shop_manager');
$args = array(
            'role__in'    => $roles,
    );
$users = get_users($args);
```